# Informix - Nothing happening when creating a db_space

Tags: informix, space

So Im trying to create a new db_space for my informix database.
I already created a file ( */matiasInformixDBSpaces/dbspace_proyectoUTU* ) and gave necessary permissions to the informix user and group.

Now, logged in as *root* user I am attempting to create a new db_space. The first one was 500 MB and this one I intended to be 1 GB. the problem I am facing is that when I run the command below, it says "Verifying physical disk space, please wait..." and it just stays there forever.

No errors or warnings are thrown. The first time I did it it was super fast. I dont know what is going on now.

```
onspaces -c -d proyectoUTUinformix -p /matiasInformixDBSpaces/dbspace_proyectoUTU -o 5000 -s 1000240
```

Can someone help me to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: The engine is allocating space on disk, if your disk is slow will take few time. If you are using Linux, create the chunk file with `fallocate` first, then the onspaces will reuse the space allocated before.

Comment: ...and you can monitor the I/O throughput of these allocation with monitors tools like atop, vmstat, sar, nmon, iotop, dstat, htop, vmstat , etc...

Comment: I’m curious about why you have a non-zero offset.   If the name refers to a raw device and the volume manager uses the start, then it makes sense. Otherwise, it is rare to use a non-zero offset. However, that has a negligible effect on speed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I dont clearly understand what that offset does, but I got a sample "recommended" comment from the web. Ill change that to zero.

Comment: @ceinmart How much time should it take? First time, when I created a 500 MB one, it only took a few seconds.

Comment: ```
fallocate -o 0 -l 1000000000 dbspace_gestionutu
  ; onspaces -c -d proyectoUTUinformix -p /matiasInformixDBSpaces/dbspace_gestionutu -o 0 -s 1000000

```
I tried fallocating the space. But the same problem occurs. onspaces does nothing.

@ceinmart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Steps towards diagnosis

I’m curious about why you have a non-zero offset. If the name refers to a raw device and the volume manager uses the start, then it makes sense. Otherwise, it is rare to use a non-zero offset. However, that has a negligible effect on speed; it just wastes a little space.

Please identify your platform, and the version of Informix you are using.

Have you looked at the size of the file from another terminal window?

```
$ a6 timecmd -m -- onspaces -c -d auxilliary -p /opt/informix/dev/$IXS.auxilliary.c0 -o 0 -s 1000240
2018-04-16 22:27:07.348 [PID 71071] onspaces -c -d auxilliary -p /opt/informix/dev/osiris_19.auxilliary.c0 -o 0 -s 1000240
Verifying physical disk space, please wait ...
Space successfully added.

** WARNING **  A level 0 archive of Root DBSpace will need to be done.
2018-04-16 22:27:07.969 [PID 71071; status 0x0000]  -  0.620s
$
```

I ran the command above on my own Mac (running macOS 10.13.4, with Informix 12.10.FC6 — I need to upgrade!) having created the empty file and set the permissions.  This Mac has solid-state disk (SSD).  The `a6` command runs programs 'as informix'; the `timecmd` echoes more timing information than the simple `time` command — start time, command executed, PID, and then finish time, exit status and duration.  I use it more for long-running commands, where knowing that it started a couple of hours ago is helpful.

Clearly, 0.620s is quick — essentially immediate.  It shouldn't take very long on your system — a few seconds at most — to write a file that's 1,024,245,760 bytes long, which is the size of the file I ended up with.

So, you need to look hard at the disk you're using. If it's a memory stick, or a remote mounted file system connected via a modem line, then it could take a long time. But a mainstream SSD or spinning disk shouldn't take very long at all.

Given what's happened, interrupt the command. Review what's in your online log file — `onstat -m` for me showed:

```
05:27:07 Space 'auxilliary' added.
05:30:18 Space 'auxilliary' dropped.
```

I run my servers in UTC time zone; I'm in US/Pacific, currently UTC-7.  Hence 22:27 locally corresponds to 05:27 in UTC.

Obviously, the 'dropped' message corresponded to my `onspaces -d auxilliary` command, run about three minutes after the add command.  If you can't find a 'space added' message in your online log file, then the operation failed.  If you find a 'space added' message, your terminal froze. (You didn't type <kbd>control-S</kbd> in it, did you?  Try a <kbd>control-Q</kbd> to restart it.) You'll need to do the archive mentioned, of course (there's one required after the drop, too) if the space was added.

Try using:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=/matiasInformixDBSpaces/dbspace_proyectoUTU bs=1024 count=1000240
```

and see how long that takes.  I ran:

```
$ a6 timecmd -m -- dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/informix/dev/$IXS.auxilliary.c0 bs=1024 count=1000240
2018-04-16 22:43:05.006 [PID 71161] a6 dd 'if=/dev/zero' 'of=/opt/informix/dev/osiris_19.auxilliary.c0' 'bs=1024' 'count=1000240'
1000240+0 records in
1000240+0 records out
1024245760 bytes transferred in 6.740104 secs (151962902 bytes/sec)
2018-04-16 22:43:11.765 [PID 71161; status 0x0000]  -  6.758s
$
```

That's much longer than the `onspaces` command, which means that `onspaces` did not write to every block in the disk file.  When I analyzed the content of the file, I got:

```
$ a6 timecmd -m -- odx $opt/$IXS.auxilliary.c0
2018-04-16 23:10:26.836 [PID 71321] odx /opt/informix/dev/osiris_19.auxilliary.c0
0x0000: 00 00 00 00 04 00 50 35 00 00 00 18 18 00 E4 0F   ......P5........
0x0010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (253)
0x0FF0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 35 16 00   ............B5..
0x1000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (255)
0x2000: 02 00 00 00 04 00 50 35 01 00 08 08 20 00 D8 0F   ......P5.... ...
0x2010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 35 00 00 00 97 D0 03 00   ........5.......
0x2020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (252)
0x2FF0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 08 00 40 35 16 00   ............@5..
0x3000: 03 00 00 00 04 00 55 35 00 00 04 08 18 00 E4 0F   ......U5........
0x3010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x3020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (252)
0x3FF0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 35 16 00   ............D5..
0x4000: 04 00 00 00 04 00 51 35 05 00 02 08 D4 00 14 0F   ......Q5........
0x4010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 40 00 01 28 00 00   ..........@..(..
0x4020: 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 10 12 8F D5 5A   ...............Z
0x4030: 01 00 00 00 32 00 00 00 32 00 00 00 32 00 00 00   ....2...2...2...
0x4040: 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 01 00 40 00   ..............@.
0x4050: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x4060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x4070: 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   ................
0x4080: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00   ................
0x4090: 18 00 6D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ..m.............
0x40A0: 61 75 78 69 6C 6C 69 61 72 79 00 69 6E 66 6F 72   auxilliary.infor
0x40B0: 6D 69 78 00 54 42 4C 53 70 61 63 65 00 00 00 00   mix.TBLSpace....
0x40C0: 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 32 00 00   .............2..
0x40D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (240)
0x4FE0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 14 00 C0 00 00 00   ................
0x4FF0: C0 00 00 00 A0 00 20 00 18 00 88 00 47 35 16 00   ...... .....G5..
0x5000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
* (64014079)
0x3D0CC000:
2018-04-16 23:10:30.808 [PID 71321; status 0x0000]  -  3.971s
$
```

As you can see, some control information was written into the first 0x5000 bytes, but thereafter, the file was all null bytes.  I'm not quite sure what it means by 'verifying physical disk space' given that the sub-second timing for `onspaces` means that it did not actually write to the space.

---

#### Resolution

If you follow the discussion in the comments below, you will see that the cause of the hold up was that the system was in the state `CKPT REQ` (checkpoint required).  This could be seen from `onstat` output, for example.  To get past that, either new logs needed to be added or the logical logs needed to be backed up.

**Caution:** By setting the backup device to `/dev/null`, you can let the server run without getting blocked, which might be OK while setting up the system, but won't be a good idea in production.

Check out the [Backup and Restore Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/bar.htm) to learn about ON-BAR and ON-Tape, the two possible backup systems.

A lot depends on the context where you'll be running the server.  If there's already a system for running backups that uses the BSA interface, using ON-BAR to integrate with that may be most appropriate.  If you don't have such a corporate backup system, then ON-Tape may be simpler.

Before you go into production, please ensure you have a proper backup strategy, and you have practiced both backups and restores of the system.
You need to be confident that your backups work.  You need to be confident that you know how to use them.

Do make sure your disks are not hard-wired directly to device names.  You can use symlinks, or use the names of files.  You need to be able to relocate the data, and hard-wired device names can make that difficult.

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for your response. Some comments I can give you. I checked the online.log and nothing important is there. Just a few failures login attempts but that was me. Regarding the hardrive, its a Linode VM server, so it should be pretty quick. In fact, the first dbspace was 500 MB and it created it in just a few seconds. Ill try to do it again by setting an offset of 0. Another thing, I am running this command as root account. Should I do it as informix user?

Comment: I have just tested as informix user and an offset of 0. It just stays there forever too. :(

Comment: There’s no significant difference between user root and user Informix for this. A non-zero offset is so much wasted space, but otherwise harmless. Does the file grow at all?   How long does the `dd` command take?

Comment: Yes. once I run the command it stays forever. So I go ahead and stop it with control C. When I *ls* the file itself, it did grew to the correct size, but I never get the message of success, and the dbspace does not show up on the dbaccess menues

Comment: 1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
1024000000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 2.48834 s, 412 MB/s

real    0m2.495s
user    0m0.280s
sys     0m2.001s

Comment: Is the Informix server up and running?   Is it stuck in a checkpoint or anything?

Comment: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC9DE -- On-Line (CKPT REQ) -- Up 3 da
ys 22:59:32 -- 164468 Kbytes
Blocked:CKPT


Yes. I can go to dbaccess and run a query on the database on the dbspace i created previously which is dbspace_matias.

Comment: total 1.4G
-rw-rw---- 1 informix informix 977M Apr 17 14:09 dbspace_gestionutu
-rw-rw---- 1 informix informix 396M Apr 14 01:13 dbspace_matias

Comment: I dont care to lose what I already have. What happens If I run oninit -i ?

Comment: would that help?

Comment: The CKPT REQ is the trouble.  The server is stuck.

Comment: ohhh. How can I get it unstuck?

Comment: Where are you backing up your logical logs?  Presumably not to `/dev/null`?   At this point, running `ontape -a` (automatic of backup) should fix the problem.

Comment: Im not backing up anything right now. Im just trying to setup everything for a small school project. Let me try Ill tell you.

Comment: Performing automatic backup of logical logs.

Please mount tape 1 on /dev/tapedev and press Return to continue ...

What can I do here? Can I redirect that path to something outside of /dev?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169177/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-matias-barrios).

Comment: Sorry. I cant reach the chat from my connection. ( Proxy blocked ). Thanks so much for your help. At least I know what is going on here now. Ill solve it and post here if I manage to do it.

Comment: `/dev/tapedev` is meant to be the name of a tape device. You could use `ln -s /dev/null /dev/tapedev` at the command line and then hit return to that prompt, and it should work.
Then you'd change the configuration to specify `/dev/null` as the backup device.  And remove the symlink `/dev/tapedev`.

Comment: That'll get you over this hump.  You'll need to reconsider your backup strategy properly, of course, before you get anywhere near production.  And configure and test it.  Several times.  Including recovery.  Several times.

Comment: Alternatively, you could reinitialize the instance with `oninit -i`, but edit the `$ONCONFIG` file to set the TAPEDEV and LTAPEDEV parameters to `/dev/null` for the time being.

Comment: Verifying physical disk space, please wait ...
Space successfully added.

** WARNING **  A level 0 archive of Root DBSpace will need to be done.


It worked. Ill edit the onconfig file. Can I redirect the TAPEDEV and LTAPEDEV to some other file? Like /matiasBackups/backuplogs ?

Comment: Glad you've got the space added!  Yes, you can set the LTAPEDEV to somewhere else, but you probably shouldn't until you have decided on what your backup strategy is.  However, if `onstat` ever reports `CKPT REQ`, you'll need to do something with `ontape` or `on-bar` (the alternative backup mechanism) to get it running again.  While you're in setup-mode and the system is 'disposable' (nothing important will be lost if there is no archive), running with `/dev/null` is reasonable.  (I do that most of the time, but many of my servers only last a day or two for testing — they're not important.)

Comment: You probably want to look into 'standard I/O' backup; I'd have to do revision on the topic because, as I said, most of my servers aren't critical.  I have a play database with the 'Table of Elements' (aka Periodic Table) as the main data.  The information in that doesn't change all that much, especially now they've completed Period VII.  Check out the [Backup and Restore Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.bar.doc/bar.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your tips. You have been simply amazing. I would give you more points if I could!!